# How to draw two line on the same xScale but different time frame

Tags: d3.js

There ara array about two month .like this

```
 [
    [{time:new Date("11/1/13"),data:1},{time:new Date("11/2/13"),data:31},...{time:new Date("11/30/13"),data:4}],
    [{time:new Date("10/1/13"),data:2},{time:new Date("10/2/13"),data:45},...{time:new Date("10/30/13"),data:14}]
 ]
```

I want to compare the data between two month on the same extent of Xcale .
I don't know how to deal with Xcale.

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([??])//how to set the domain 
            .range([0,300])
            .nice();
```

Answer (score 1):

Naming your two arrays `data`:

```
var data = [
    [{time:new Date("11/1/13"),data:1},{time:new Date("11/2/13"),data:31},...{time:new Date("11/30/13"),data:4}],
    [{time:new Date("10/1/13"),data:2},{time:new Date("10/2/13"),data:45},...{time:new Date("10/30/13"),data:14}]
 ]
```

Temporally combine the arrays with merge `merge`, extract the date object with `map`, and get the range with `extent`:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
            .domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(data).map(function(d){ return d.time; }))
            .range([0,300])
```